# How to use Power Bi Rain Bow Gauge?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, gauge

I wanna use Power Bi Rain Bow Gauge. but I have difficulty in choosing the parameter. I need to know the concept of the gauge and the type of the parameters it gives. for example i want to show the rate of damage over the total sell.

Comment: add your sample data and expected output here.

Comment: I have a sigma for total sale and a sigma for total damage. I wanna show the rate of damage/sell if it is less than 0.5 with green, between 0.5 and 0.75 with yellow and more than  0.75 with red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **TachoMeter** for your purpose. Add this visual from **AppSource** to your Power BI Desktop. Now follow these below steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1:** Create your damage/sell measure as below-

```
ratio = SUM(your_table_name[damage])/SUM(your_table_name[sell])
```

**Step-2:** Create these below **4 measure** to set different point in the TachoMeter-

```
1. point_1 = 0
2. point_2 = 0.5
3. point_3 = 0.75
4. point_4 = 1
```

Now configure your TachoMeter as shown in the below image. You can also see your final output in the image-

[image]

Comment: your suggestion helped me and for a while worked great. but now the needle does not stand in the correct place. the tachometer calls out the correct value, but the needle always shows the max value. It would be great if you help me to fix the needle

Comment: I think you can post a new question explaining the details (with all data point) and scenario :)